# Confusion between inheritance and specificity in CSS

Tags: html, css, inheritance

Following is the html file I am working to understand difference between these two rules in CSS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>specificity</title>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  <style>
    aside,
    article,
    section,
    header,
    footer,
    nav {
      display: block;
    }
    body {
      font-family: Georgia;
      font-size: 120%;
    }
    /*add styles here*/
    #mainContent p {
      color: red;
    }
    p {
      color: blue;
    }
    .green {
      color: green;
    }
    /**/
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="mainContent">
    <p>I am a paragraph nested inside a section. I also have a <strong class="green">strong tag</strong> nested inside of me.</p>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

And following is the statement I didn't understand quite clearly:

> Specificity works just fine until inheritance is involved. If a child
>   element has a style that differs or conflicts with the parent styles,
>   the child styles always win. So for `strong` element above, we are seeing inheritance and not specificity.

But if I apply `green` class to `<p>` element, I am observing specificity since style green is ignored and style with id applied to paragraph.

My question is, since `<p>` is a child of `<section>` shouldn't inheritance be observed here according to above statement, just like it's observed with `<strong>` element?

Comment: In your example, the `<strong>` element's color is not coming from inheritance. Where does that quote come from?

Comment: It came from a course I am doing in Lynda.

Comment: *Specificity works just fine until inheritance is involved.* - That statement seems to be wrong @Kiran. It should be the other way around if my English skills are decent :P

Comment: I think it's correct statement. Since <strong> element's color is changed to green because it's child of section and child rule wins in inheritance. Here specificity didn't apply to this element.

Comment: Specificity is the one that is applied to your `strong` element. It is green in color because you've assigned the green class to the `strong` element (specifically to that element). If it had inherited style from parent, it would have been red in color and not green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every CSS rule only applies to the *subject* of its selector.

For `p { ... }` the *subject* is all `p` elements

For `#mainContent p { ... }`  the *subject* is all `p` elements which are inside the element with id `mainContent`.

if a `p` element is inside the element with id `mainContent`, the `#mainContent p { ... }` rule wins because it is a more *specific* rule.

The `strong` element is not the *subject* of either rule, so neither applies directly.

In the example, the strong element is the subject of the `.green { ... }` rule. So that is the rule that applies to that element.

So where does inheritance come in?

Inheritance of a property to an element can happen in one of two ways.

First, there can be an explicit rule whose *subject* is the element and the property setting is `inherit`. So `strong { color:inherit; }` will, if it is the highest priority rule with the color property in the cascade for a `strong` element, force the color of that element to be taken from that of its parent.

Alternatively, if there is no rule anywhere in the cascade for which a given `strong` element has a particular property defined, that element will take a default value. Some properties are defined as "inherited" and others are not. The `color` property is defined as inherited.

So, in this alternative case, only when that there is no rule whose *subject* is a given element and has a `color` property, does the color of that given element get inherited from the color of the containing element.

In your example. there are multiple rules for which the p element is the subject and the color element is defined, so no inheritance is effective on that.